# How to select and replace similar occurrences in a column

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-cleaning

I'm working on a ML project for a class. I'm currently cleaning the data and I encountered a problem. I basically have a column (which is identified as dtype object) that has ratings about a certain aspect in a hotel. When i checked what the values of this column were and in what frequency they appeared, I noticed that there are some wrong values in it (as you can see below, instead of ratings, some rows have a date as a value)

```
rating       value_counts()      
100           527
98            229
97            172
99            163
96            150
95            127
93            100
90             94
94             93
80             65
92             55
91             39
88             35
89             32
87             31
85             25
86             17
84             12
60             12
83              8
70              5
73              5
82              4
78              3
67              3
2018-11-11      3
20              2
81              2
2018-11-03      2
40              2
79              2
75              2
2018-10-26      2
2               1
2018-08-30      1
2018-09-03      1
2015-09-05      1
55              1
2018-10-12      1
2018-05-11      1
2018-11-14      1
2018-09-15      1
2018-04-07      1
2018-08-16      1
71              1
2018-09-18      1
2018-11-05      1
2018-02-04      1
NaN             1
```

What I wanted to do was to replace all the values that look like dates with NaN so I can later fill them with appropriate values. Is there a good way to do this other than selecting each different date one by one and replacing it with a NaN? Is there a way to select similar values (in this case all the dates that start in the same way, 2018) and replace them all?

Thank you for taking the time to read this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options to clean this data.

Option 1: Rating column is ofobject type, search the strings by presence of '-' and replace with np.nan

```
df.loc[df['rating'].str.contains('-', na = False), 'rating'] = np.nan
```

Option 2: Convert the column to numeric which will coerce the dates to nan.

```
df['rating'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rating'], errors = 'coerce')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I just tried to implement the first option and I get this error: ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values. 
Is this because I already have other NaN values? And if so, how can I fix it?

Comment: There is a parameter na = False, using that the first option works. see the edit